# CCHttpRequest not found using Coccos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am using Eclipse and Cocos2d-x for my game development. I have included the `#include "cocos-ext.h"`in my header file, and added `extensions/` path to my eclipse include path. Eclipse finds the cocos-ext.h file but but it cannot seem to find the `CCHttpRequest` classes ? As per my understanding, all the CCHttpRequest files are included in the cocos-ext.h file.

This is my sample code

```
    CCHttpRequest* request = new CCHttpRequest();
    request->setUrl("http://just-make-this-request-failed.com");
    request->setRequestType(CCHttpRequest::kHttpGet);
    request->setTag("GET test1");
    CCHttpClient::getInstance()->send(request);
    request->release();
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to prefix your calls to the extensions classes like so:

```
cocos2d::extension::CCHttpRequest* http = new cocos2d::extension::CCHttpRequest();
```

OR if you want to leave your code as is, you will need to add the appropriate namespace.

Comment: Thank you. Thats was the problem. Thank you.